# Receiving 'jwt malformed' message when trying to load my website initially with Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, redux, react-redux

Upon login I have my initial component that calls a Redux action but after logging in the user `token` isn't sent fast enough to be received by the axios header, if I `console.log(token)` before and after the `axios.create({ headers: auth: token })` it shows null, so of course I'm going to get 'jwt malformed' but how can I set up my app to wait for the token to load before running the Redux file? I've tried a check before running my `dispatch` to make sure there is a `token` but the file is running even before that is hit.

```
// Shoes component
useEffect(() => {
    const { sortby } = props;
    dispatch(getShoesAsync(sortby)).then((response) => {
      setLoading(false);
    });
  }, [dispatch, props]);

//Redux token auth
const userTokenAxios = axios.create({
  baseURL: '/api/shoes',
  headers: {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`,
  },
});

// Redux action
export const getShoesAsync = createAsyncThunk(
  'shoes/getShoesAsync',
  async (payload, { rejectWithValue }) => {
    try {
      const response = await userTokenAxios.get(`?sortby=${payload}`);
      return response.data;
    } catch (error) {
      return rejectWithValue(error.response.data);
    }
  }
);
```